# GetUserAsync in Razor EF ASP.NET Core return null when already sign in?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Why does GetUserAsync return null ?

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> lambda_method178(Closure )
> InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.GetValue(Expression expression, out string parameterName)
> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at lambda_method178(Closure )

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using different branches with different DB, and claims ID were different, so when I signed in and debugged one then I went to another branched and sign in automatically, that when the error started. So Sign out and sign in again solve the problem, because claims where different that you put in GetUserAsync().